# When a problem in data structures mentions to solve it in O(n) space complexity, does it mean that I can use only one external data structure or more?

Tags: data-structures, space-complexity

I have a very basic question. When a problem in data structures mentions to solve it in O(n) space complexity, does it mean that I can use only one external data structure or more? As an example, if an array problem mentions to solve it in O(n) space complexity, does that mean that I can use only one array ? or I can use more than one array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many data structures as you want, so long as their combined size is within `O(n)`.  If there are a fixed number of such data structures and each one is in `O(n)` then the total will also be within `O(n)`.

Loops have to do with CPU complexity, not Space complexity.